How can I review changes in the project.pbxproj file that is being tracked in git?
Well, I am facing project.pbxproj file in my project appears in the tracked files in the Sourcetree client app. There's no changes preview possibility and it would be nice to see what was edited on this document just to ensure the deleted or created documents were being reflected on it. I would like to know if there's some way to see these changes.

git diff will show you this.

Xcode will "always" want to render the project file as chrome in Xcode UI.
The file an XML-style file, so if you use git diff you can casually see differences, but it might be hard to see the context, especially if you do not want to explore the structure of the XML.
If you use VSCode, I would view it in side-by-side mode.
